# unable to get value from $_FILES

Tags: php, html

I'm just not getting the Strings from $_FILES["file"]["name"], $_FILES["file"]["type"], and so on. It's my first time using $_FILES. In which way Could I improve the code so I get the echo from the strings? I've read every tutorial already. here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input type="file" name="file">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
   {
       echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
       echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
       echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
       echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
   }
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` and let's see what you've got.

Comment: you didn't specify the name in button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your submit input does not have a name attribute so its value cant be sent when the form is submitted. Set its name attribute to submit and them your isset check will pass

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much @Musa  I wouldn't know I just needed something that simple

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
```

use this on submit input your code run

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     var_dump($_FILES);
     //OR
     print_r($_FILES);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use print_r($_FILES); not echo

You checks

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

but you are missing name="submit" in your form.